# How do I use Lightning Components is a Visualforce page that is part of a Site or Community?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We know there have been many of you trying to get this to work and we have fixed the underlying issue.

Answer (score 5):

Heads up for folks using Lightning Components for Visualforce that have not been able to use their pages with Communities/Sites:

The fix for this should be on all instances now. We've also released a new Visualforce component to make this even easier (no need to worry about sessionID or base URLs). Documentation update will be out next week but this is the short version: just change:

```
<apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
```

to:

```
<apex:includeLightning/>
```

and you should be good to go for all contexts where your Visualforce page can be used.

**NOTE**: you should never have to specify baseURL or sessionID when using LC4VF from this point forward as long as you leverage `<apex:includeLightning/>`